# webdriverio: read and write data

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, data-driven-tests

How can we implement data driven approach in webdriverIO?
In selenium we can define properties file or write data to Excel.
For example, if I need to store date in a variable and implement the rest of the scenario's based on the date value(even if I need to get date value for second day or third day based on first day).
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you